# Plot the Minkowski distance with different p

Tags: r, distance

As we know, when we calculate the [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance), we can get different distance value with different p (The power of the Minkowski distance).

For example, when p=1, the points whose Minkowski distance equal to 1 from (0, 0) combine a square. In R, dist() function can get the distance.

My question is with different p, I want to plot the distance with different p to get graphs like below.

[image]

Comment: `dist` has minkowski method, see examples [here](https://davetang.org/muse/2013/08/15/distance-matrix-computation/). `dist(data[1:2,], method="minkowski", p=2)`